# Browser can't open an app from a browser using deeplink

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I'm trying to implement deeplinks in my, so users will be able to open the application from a browser. So, I've added deeplinks in my application in a Manifest.xml. And this code is working from adb, but when I'm trying to open this link in browser, the application does not opens. What can cause this error? I can even can't see an Intent in my code

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can u share the exact link to which it needs to be redirected?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but you can add an any link, this code doesn't work at all

Comment: Well, I figured out. I had two <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>. Can work only one

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase deep link ( Hope Help-full )

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links